# проблема с кодировкой при записи в базу mysql на heroku

Tags: mysql, heroku

Здравствуйте, перенес таблицу на heroku таблица в utf-8. Всё отображается нормально, но если сделать новую запись, русские символы отображаются - `???` У меня на компьютере всё постилось нормально.
 В чем проблема?

Comment: а базу(schema) создавали с кодировкой `utf8_general_ci`?

Comment: @MrFylypenko да

Answer (score 1):

проблему решил добавил к url `?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8` и всё теперь записывается.